What is the Jehovahs Witness theology on Satan
Was he created evil or did he become evil? If he was someone else and then became evil, when did this happen?

https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/did-god-create-the-devil/

the url cited states "we can conclude" that Satan was once one of Gods angelic sons. Please supply biblical references for that conclusion that are contrary to Revelation 12:7 "Then a war broke out in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon, and the dragon and his angels fought back. 8But the dragon was not strong enough, and no longer was any place found in heaven for him and his angels. 9And the great dragon was hurled down—that ancient serpent called the devil and Satan, the deceiver of the whole world. He was hurled to the earth, and his angels with him."

@adam if you ask for a denomination's beliefs they may not have biblical-basis

@adam. https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/where-does-the-devil-live/

In JW's "Insight on the Scriptures, Volume 2 p. 866" you'll find the following on "Satan":

Origin. The Scriptures indicate that the creature known as Satan did not always have that name. Rather, this descriptive name was given
to him because of his taking a course of opposition and resistance to
God. The name he had before this is not given. God is the only
Creator, and ‘his activity is perfect,’ with no injustice or
unrighteousness. (De 32:4) Therefore, the one becoming Satan was, when
created, a perfect, righteous creature of God. He is a spirit person,
for he appeared in heaven in the presence of God. (Job chaps 1, 2; Re
12:9) Jesus Christ said of him: “That one was a manslayer when he
began, and he did not stand fast in the truth, because truth is not in
him.” (Joh 8:44; 1Jo 3:8) Jesus here shows that Satan was once in the
truth, but forsook it. Beginning with his first overt act in turning
Adam and Eve away from God, he was a manslayer, for he thereby brought
about the death of Adam and Eve, which, in turn, brought sin and death
to their offspring. (Ro 5:12) Throughout the Scriptures the qualities
and actions attributed to him could be attributed only to a person,
not to an abstract principle of evil. It is clear that the Jews, and
Jesus and his disciples, knew that Satan existed as a person.
So, from a righteous, perfect start, this spirit person deviated into
sin and degradation. The process bringing this about is described by
James when he writes: “Each one is tried by being drawn out and
enticed by his own desire. Then the desire, when it has become
fertile, gives birth to sin; in turn, sin, when it has been
accomplished, brings forth death.” (Jas 1:14, 15) In the course that
Satan took, there seems to be, in some respects, a parallel with that
of the king of Tyre as described in Ezekiel 28:11-19.
The Scriptural account, therefore, makes it plain that it was Satan
who spoke through the medium of a serpent, seducing Eve into
disobedience to God’s command. In turn, Eve induced Adam to take the
same rebellious course. (Ge 3:1-7; 2Co 11:3) As a consequence of
Satan’s use of the serpent, the Bible gives Satan the title “Serpent,”
which came to signify “deceiver”; he also became “the Tempter” (Mt
4:3) and a liar, “the father of the lie.”​—Joh 8:44; Re 12:9.

So according to Jehovah's Witnesses, was Satan created evil or did he become evil?
He wasn't created evil but became evil by his own free will.
If he was someone else and then became evil, when did this happen?
It must have developed in his figurative heart during or shortly after the creation of Adam and Eve - jealousy probably played a role here. What God created was "very good", causing admiration by the creation towards the creator. This was something the Spirit being who later was called Satan wanted for himself - he willfully was being "drawn out and enticed by his own desire", ultimately causing sin and death.
